# Syntax error missing operator in query expression SUM

Tags: sql, ms-access

I think the query is okay, but still facing error :

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(...
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT af.USERID, SUM(
    IIf(af.CHECKTIME Is Not Null,
        IIf(WeekDay(DateValue(af.CHECKTIME)) <> 6 And Format(af.CHECKTIME, 'hh:nn:ss') <= '08:15:00', 
            1, IIf(Format(af.CHECKTIME, 'hh:nn:ss') <= '08:30:00', 1, 0)
        ),
        IIf(bf.CHECKTIME Is Not Null,
            IIf(WeekDay(DateValue(bf.CHECKTIME)) <> 6 And Format(bf.CHECKTIME, 'hh:nn:ss') <= '08:15:00', 
                1, IIf(Format(bf.CHECKTIME, 'hh:nn:ss') <= '08:30:00', 1, 0)
            ), 0
        )
    ) AS [CAME ON TIME OR EARLY]  
FROM (CHECKINOUT AS af
    LEFT JOIN CHECKEXACT bf ON  af.USERID = bf.USERID)
    WHERE af.USERID = 6 And af.CHECKTIME Between #3/1/2020# And #3/31/2020#  GROUP BY af.USERID
```

I have checked the query multiple times but i think there is no problem in it.

Could you tell me which syntax that i am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
) AS [CAME ON TIME OR EARLY]
```

You close the parenthese of this `IIf(af.CHECKTIME Is Not Null,` but you need to close the paranthses for the sum as well

```
)) AS [CAME ON TIME OR EARLY]
```

You can use search to see that you open 16 parantheses but only close 15.

Comment: Oh Thanks Gabriel. How could i miss that hahaha